# Search array with logical condition

Tags: sql, arrays, vb.net, logical-operators

I have integer array for which I have to check whether items meet the logical condition.
For example:

```
array: [1, 4, 17, 22, 45]
condition: 1 AND 17 AND (22 OR 49)
```

How to check that elements of array fulfill the condition.
I have elements of array stored in DB as rows with common identifier:

```
ID_1 | 1
ID_1 | 4
ID_1 | 17
ID_1 | 22
ID_1 | 45
```

If someone has any idea how to check that those values meet condition through SQL or search across array I would be grateful.

Comment: What is the structure of the table. Without the structure of the database, one cannot answer this.

Comment: Are you asking how to write a WHERE condition for a SELECT query?

Comment: It is a table of items of the invoice. Each row represent item with its identificator (integer value) and I have to check whether the invoice (ID_1) has items that correspond to the logical condition. Table has few more columns (price, amount, ...) but invoice ID and item ID are field for check that ivoice items meet condition.

Comment: Look into using a List(Of T) with .Find/.FindAll() instead of an array. (or perhaps the Array has a Find? I didn't look.) .Find()uses a lambda that can be made as complex as you need.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
Module StartupModule

    Sub Main()
        Dim nums() As Integer = {1, 4, 17, 22, 45}

        Dim hasNumbers As Func(Of Integer(), Boolean) = Function(arr)
                                                            Return arr.Contains(1) AndAlso arr.Contains(17) AndAlso (arr.Contains(22) OrElse arr.Contains(49))
                                                        End Function

        Dim result As Boolean = hasNumbers(nums)

        Console.WriteLine(result)

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

**EDIT**

It won't do as just now read that condition would be anything. So I would use [expression trees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to find invoices containing item id 1 AND 17 AND (22 OR 49). Then you can do

```
SELECT invoice_id 
FROM items
WHERE item_id IN (1, 17, 22)
GROUP BY invoice_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
UNION
SELECT invoice_id 
FROM items
WHERE item_id IN (1, 17, 49)
GROUP BY invoice_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

This works only if the `item_id`s are unique per invoice.

Comment: condition can be anything, like 2 OR (5 AND 7 AND 15) so I need universal approach. I tought to cnvert rows into array and then applay logical condition on it.

Comment: Translate to words: if i have apple and bananas in invoice then I need to add specific text on the bottom. That can be anything like if I have (onion or garlic) and egg then I'll write on the bottom "nice scrambled eggs"

Comment: If you read the data into an array, this would not be an SQL question at all. But where is your problem exactly? Can't you do something like `array.Contains(1) AndAlso array.Contains(17) AndAlso (array.Contains(22) OrElse array.Contains(49))`?

Comment: Condition can be anything, user crate condition trough console and they can make any correct logical expression. I used contains in the end as a part of checking if item in condition exist in array of items but only after I applied reverse logic to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in the reverse logic. For each element in a condition that represents an item (not braces or logical operand, so integer) I checked whether it is element of array. If it is then it's replaced with true, otherwise with fasle.
So I get something like this:

```
array: [1, 4, 17, 22, 45]
original conditions
  condition A: 1 AND 17 AND (22 OR 49)
  condition B: 17 AND 45
will turn into 
  condition A: true AND true AND (true OR false)
  condition B: true AND true
```

Then I just need to make function that will evaluate string with boolean expression into true or false.

Here [is example](http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27618508/C-NET-How-to-Evaluate-the-boolean-string-expression-in-NET.html) how to evaluate logical expression.

So I didnt test array with condition then check if items in condition exist or not in array and replace them with true/false. With that I got a logical expression that should be evaluated.